# Front end login and check not working correctly

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the code below to allow front-end login, I then have a different menu depending if they're logged in or not.

The problem I'm having is that once the user clicks login and they get redirected to another page, the menu that is shown there is correct but when they click on another page it reverts to the "not logged in" menu even though no logout buttons have been clicked.

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="<?php echo esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php', 'login_post' ) ); ?>" method="post">
  <p>
    <label for="user_login">
      <?php _e('Username') ?>
      <br />
      <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr($user_login); ?>" size="20" tabindex="10" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="user_pass">
      <?php _e('Password') ?>
      <br />
      <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" tabindex="20" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <?php do_action('login_form'); ?>
  <p class="forgetmenot">
    <label for="rememberme">
      <input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" tabindex="90"<?php checked( $rememberme ); ?> />
      <?php esc_attr_e('Remember Me'); ?>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p class="submit">
    <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Log In'); ?>" tabindex="100" />
    <?php   if ( $interim_login ) { ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="interim-login" value="1" />
    <?php   } else { ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/dashboard" />
    <?php   } ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />
  </p>
</form>
```

The code below is what I'm using around the menu to show a different one depending if they're logged in or out:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
} else {
} ?>
```

---

It looks as though the session is getting destroyed once logged in. It saves it initially but clicking on any other links destroys the session!

Comment: are you using any caching plugins?

Comment: @doublesharp Nope, I've even disabled all other plugins and still the same thing happens.

Comment: What happens if you:  var_dump(is_user_logged_in()) exit;  on the second page?  It sounds like your using 2 different templates.

Answer (score 4):

Try it slightly differently, as below:

```
 <?php 

  if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
         //no user logged in
      } else {
        // Hello!
      }
 ?>
```

Edit: It appars that is_user_logged_in() has some issues: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21043

We can do this in a diffreent approach, of course. Let's get the user information, and check variables based on that.

```
<?php
    global $current_user; // Make it global
    get_currentuserinfo(); // Get the current user info
    $userID = $current_user->ID; // Get the User ID

    if($userID) { // Logged in because there is a User ID. 

        echo "Hello Mate";

    } else { // Logged out

        echo "Tumbleweed";
    } 
?>
```

I was scratching my head when this didnt work in my environment, so make sure you aren't logged in as admin in the same browser.

You are also welcome to put this into a function, depending on what your after.

Comment: I tried reversing it but no luck! How would I do it via variables?

Comment: Still the same thing happens. When I login via the front end form, after clicking submit it redirects me to another page (with the menu as if logged in - which is correct) but when I then click on another section the menu changes to show the logged out one.

Comment: Do you have an example I can see live or is it local? Is it just a private site?

Comment: If you have a look at http://www.frontiersharpsafety.com/v1/, you should be able to login with the details username: tester, p/w: test101 on the right login boxes. The menu with home at the top is the logged out menu, with dashboard at the top is the logged in menu. Cheers for this.

Comment: Have you fixed this? I don't see 'Home' when logged in.

Comment: If you login, then click on training or tests the menu changes back to the logged out version (home) for me. If you click any links after it logs you in then the menu reverts to the logged out version everytime.

Comment: I think it is down to your site structure. It's obviously grabbing the user info sucessfully. Try outputting the the user ID at the very top in your header.php and see what is happening.

Comment: I've placed it above the menu. It's saying 0 when logged out and 1 when logged in. When you login and then click on tests/training it says 0 again. Not sure why it isn't saving it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17304/discussion-between-smacfadyen-and-rob)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the "theme my login" plugin, besides making your login page as a front-end page, it will add a widget with a quick login form.